# Is it possible to loop for comprehension with IO

Tags: scala, haskell, scalaz

I'm talking about this Haskell example:

```
main = do   
    line <- getLine  
    if null line  
        then return ()  
        else do  
            putStrLn $ reverseWords line  
            main
```

Is it possible to translate it in scala with `IO` monad?

Instead of return I wanted to use `if` in for-comprehension. I am really not sure about looping it with a recursive call. It sounds like scala does not allow that. If not, what is the proper way of doing it?

Also it seems like `IO` does not have `filter`, even this doesn't work:

```
import scalaz._
import effect._
import IO._

for {
   line <- readLn if !line.empty
   _ <- putStrLn(line)
} yield ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible in scala since `if` clause is lazy in scala too. Other tricks involving lazy evaluations may not be that intuitive though.

```
import scalaz._, effect._, IO._

def main: IO[Unit] = for {
  line <- readLn
  _ <- if (line.isEmpty) {
    Monad[IO].point(())
  } else {
    for {
      _ <- putStrLn(line)
      _ <- main
    } yield ()
  }
} yield ()
```

Comment: This sounds like a nice try, but it causes `forward reference extends over definition of value main _ <- main`. This is the same error I received when I tried recursive approach. But that answers at least my question about `if`. I still wouldn't call it that intuitive :)

Comment: Ah, I've just made `val main` into `def main` and that made it working. Perfect! I've made a fix to the answer, hope you don't mind

Comment: @Archeg As `val` works and compiles on my machine, maybe we are using different version of scala. Thanks for your edit!

Comment: Just FYI: I've investigated a bit and it looks like using `val` as recursive only possible if it is a field. I had it as a local variable, that's why it didn't work. `def` or `lazy val` should work always